# how do i know if the logic of my programme right?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ipython

my homework is to write a programme that calculates a taxi fare. However, the taxi is charging a £2.00 base fare plus £2.00 per mile for each of the first five miles and £1.00 per mile for each mile thereafter. and the teacher gave us a hint saying that we can write the part that calculates the fare as a function

this is what i did...
there is no error, but the only problem is that my programme doesn't work when entering any distance

```
user_fare = int(input('Please enter the distance '))
if user_fare == 0:
    print('2')
elif user_fare > 0 and user_fare < 5:
    def distance_into_money(fare):
        return ((user_fare*2)+2)
        print(distance_into_money)
elif user_fare > 5:
    def distance_into_money(fare):
        return ((user_fare*2)+1)
        print(distance_into_money)
else:
    print('Error')
```

i expect the output of 1 mile to be '£4.00' and output of 6 miles to be '£13.00' and  output of -1 miles to be an 'error' but my programme has no output

Comment: How to make sure? As the teacher said, write a function which takes distance as argument and returns the fare. Then, calculate (by hand) the correct value for a few representative distances (e.g. 0, 1, 2.5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 50 miles) and verify that the result is correct fo all of them. Also, google `unittest`.

Comment: The two `elif` statements define functions, but they don't run them.  Those definitions have their own problem.  The `print` after the `return` line can't be executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function distance_into_money should be defined outside of your logic statements. And it would be better for you to work the logic into that function to begin with.

Let's re-work your logic as well:

1. Under 5 miles, the fare is $2 (base) + $2 / mile.
2. Over 5 miles, the fare is $2(base) + $2 / mile * 5 (for 5 miles) + $1 / mile (for each mile over 5). Re-working this all into your code, we get

```py
# Defining our function first allows us to use it later.
# None of the code in the function is executed until you call the function later
def distance_into_money(dist):
    if 0 <= dist <= 5: # Python supports logical statements like this
        return 2 + (dist*2)
    if dist > 5:
        return 2 + (2*5) + 1*(dist-5)
        # Again, this is $2 base + $2/mil * 5 mil + $1/mi * (number of miles over 5 miles)
    return -1 # Indicates there was an error: The dist was not in the acceptable bounds

users_distance = int(input("Please enter the distance "))
users_fare = distance_into_money(users_distance)
if users_fare == -1: # There was an error
    print("Error")
else: #There was not an error
    print("The user's fare is ${}".format(users_fare))

# The str.format method replaces the {} with its argument (which is the user's fare in this case).
```